# Does decompiled C# get reverse engineered from IL/MSIL?

Tags: c#

When I open a tool like ILSpy or dotPeek, I have an option of viewing decompiled C# or the IL.

When you view the decompiled source, does the decompiler reverse engineer the IL into the decompiled C# equivalent?

If so then how would a decompiler infer such a case as the IL below? (do note that this is a trivial example of the first language construct that came to mind which couldn't easily be inferred from IL, as opposed to actual output from a decompiler):

```
IL_0000: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
IL_0001: ldstr "C"            // Push a string object for the literal string
IL_0006: stloc.0              // Pop a value from stack into local variable 0
IL_0007: ret
```

Translate to:

```
public class C {
    public void M() {
        string foo = nameof(C);
    }
}
```

Comment: "When you view the decompiled source, does the decompiler reverse engineer the IL into the decompiled C# equivalent?" Yes. At least, it tries.

Comment: Yes and the creators of the tool symply analyzed how the Microsoft C# compiler (and the Mono compiler probably) produces code for common samples. For this reason sometimes there are pieces of "undecompilable" code.

Comment: Which decompiler did you use that decompiled to a use of `nameof`?

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't use a decompiler in this case, I was trying to think of a language construct that couldn't be translated from IL to decompiled C# to illustrate my point.

Comment: Well, it *could* be translated to decompiled C# by the decompiler observing that the name "C" exists as one of the names in the assembly. But there'd be no guarantee that `nameof` was in the original source code. I suggest you reword the question, as in its current form it strongly suggests that decompilers *do* infer that, when in practice I haven't seen them do so.

Comment: Good thinking, reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the decompilation tools have to reverse engineer from the IL.

This is why the tools need to be updated for each version of C#/VB, if you want them to decompile newly introduced language features. Otherwise, if the tool is not updated, it will either give up on trying to decompile it or it will produce highly convoluted code that a maniac *could* have written in an earlier version of the language but most probably did not.

Some decompilation tools will also attempt to locate the actual source code (via PDBs and Source Servers), and if they're successful in this endeavour then you will see the actual source and of course no decompilation effort occurs in this case.

Comment: ...newly introduced language features ... in a way that is not a total spagetti.

Comment: So I presume that unless you have the pdb files then you can't trust the decompiled output?

Comment: @doker I'm italian, so I'm offended for your error: it is *spaghetti* :-)

Comment: @JosephWoodward - PDB files aren't much help. They will allow e.g. local variable names to sometimes be recovered but they don't really guide the decompilation process most of the time.

Comment: @JosephWoodward - but, of course, PDB files are a great help if the tool you're using will use those to see whether it can obtain the *actual* source code rather than trying to decompile it.

Comment: @xanatos: Sorry mate, I've got a little entangled :)

Answer (score 6):

Sure those tools will try to reverse engineer from MSIL, but speaking of your particular example - it is not possible to reverse engineer your MSIL to

```
public class C {
    public void M() {
        string foo = nameof(C);
    }
}
```

Without extenal guidance, like symbol (.pdb) files. Try to compile that statement above in a library, then delete ".pdb" file and put .dll into dotPeek. You will see that it will decompile it as expected:

```
public void M()
{
    string foo = "C";
}
```

Now put .pdb file back and you will see your `nameof(C)` expression back.

Now put .pbd file back, but change the location of source code you used to compile that .dll (for example, rename project folder, delete it completely, or just move .dll with .pdb to different machine). Load it again in dotPeek and you will see again `string foo = "C";`. That is because .pdb symbols might contain path to your actual source code (you might see those paths in exception stack traces for example), which is then used by decompiler tools to show it directly without any decompilation.

Comment: Not saying I don't trust your example, but why did your decompiler choose to insert a `Console.WriteLine`? :-)

Comment: Yeah I've messed up my example, fixed :)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer (especially about moving the source), I wish I could mark both answers as the correct one.

Comment: Latest EAP of dotPeek now have proper decompilation of assemblies that used `nameof()` in their original source code.

Comment: @NikolayKostov how they do it without access to original source code?

Comment: @Evk probably using `.pdb`'s. I asked myself the same question and did not find any differences in the IL code when using `nameof` and just a string.